# Can Ubuntu launcher damage my LCD screen pixels?

Tags: 12.04, launcher, display, screen

There appears something like a scar (damaged or dead pixels) on my LCD screen, where Ubuntu launcher positions. The scar exactly fitting Ubuntu launcher edges and icons. It seems a permanent scar and it stays even if I load other operating systems.

Can this damage be a cause of Ubuntu launcher?

I know this is a stupid question, but I decided to ask here because this is exactly fitting Ubuntu launcher edges and icons.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Samsung LCD.

My system details as follows:

[image]

Comment: I've never heard of the Ubuntu launcher causing damaging, it would be helpful if you posted your laptop specs (along with current graphics drivers/whether it has 3d acceleration).

Comment: Also don't worry about asking questions which you find stupid: the only stupid question is the one not asked ;)

Comment: This is a desktop PC with Samsung 39 cm TFT LCD. Model No: 632NW.

Comment: That's just the screen model right? Seeing as the model is recent I don't think your problem is with the screen, could you add the information to your question and also add your system's specs from [System settings]->[System]->[Details].

Comment: Also a Photo of it will be extremely useful

Comment: @Oyibo I added my system details

Comment: @Anwar Of course, a photo of the screen definitely add value to this question, but unfortunately I have no facility to take a shot at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's called LCD screen image persistence.  The Good news appears to be that unlike plasma screen and phosphor screen burn-in, persistence is generally reversible.

It's caused by the the liquid crystals that are in a turned on state for very long periods of time not "relaxing" completely back to the non-activated state.  There's two main approaches to reversing the problem:

### Solution 1

Turn the screen off and do not use it for an extended period of time.  This may vary from a few days to a few weeks, depending on the nature of the liquid crystals and how bad the problem is.

### Solution 2

Set up a screen saver that is one white image that covers the entire screen.  Set the screen saver to activate in a short amount of time, say one or two minutes.  Set the screen to turn off after about 15 minutes of inactivity.  This way, when the computer is idle it will display the white screen for less than 15 minutes, then go blank.  After a period of this you should see the problem lessen and eventually go away.  When the problem is fixed you can go back to a normal screen saver, or simply do as I do and set the screen to turn off after a reasonable amount of time.

The last solution (2) is one that seems to be suggested a lot, however I believe that the first solution is most likely to reverse the problem completely and in the shortest possible time.

Comment: Nice and interesting answer! Great job!

Answer (score 0):

Use the tool "lcdscrub": http://toastycode.com/lcdscrub/

It also can be found in the packages xscreensaver-data-extra